# View share in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-5

I have this class and `$total_mess` variable to count the message that user haven't read. I have the problem that no matter if the user is logged in or not I just receive `$total_mess` with an empty string (for second if condition).

```php
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use App\Chat;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $total_mess = Chat::whereRaw('view = ?  and  to_user = ?', [0, Auth::user()->username])->count();
            view()->share('total_mess', $total_mess);
        }
        if (Auth::guest()) {
            view()->share('total_mess', '');
        }
    }
```

So how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this in your boot method, it will make available your variable once view are ready, this will only available in Views

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
{
   if (Auth::check()) {
     $total_mess = Chat::whereRaw('view = ?  and  to_user = ?', [0, Auth::user()->username])->count();
     $view->with('total_mess', $total_mess);
   }

   if (Auth::guest()) {
      $view->with('total_mess', $total_mess);
   }

});
```

**Edited**

if you also want to access it in your controller as will as views, then try this instead of above method

```
app()->singleton('total_mess',function($app){

   if (Auth::check()) {
     $total_mess = Chat::whereRaw('view = ?  and  to_user = ?', [0, Auth::user()->username])->count();
   }

   if (Auth::guest()) {
      $total_mess = '';
   }

      return $total_mess;

});
```

and can access the value using this `App::make('friend_new_req_count')`

Comment: Thanks i will try it out